# Align images to paragraphs in step-by-step process instructions (Microsoft Word)

Tags: microsoft-word, documentation

I am trying to reformat step-by-step manufacturing process instructions that someone else created in Microsoft Word - each one is about 10 pages long. The current documents do not do a good job of associating specific instructions with images or making effective use of whitespace. Each one is laid out as one monolithic table with each row being one step in the process.

I want to create a layout that clearly associates instructions on the left with a diagram on the right for each step. Additionally, I want to use heading styles to be able to summarize the process steps with a Table of Contents on the first page, and also use the navigation pane to navigate the steps. Lastly, I need to minimize the use of complicated or advanced layout techniques since I won't be the one managing these long-term. However, none of the methods I've tried accomplish this satisfactorily.

This is ideally suited for a two-column table layout, and has the advantage of not having to teach people how to deal with the complexities of image wrapping, but the headings within the table do not show up in the navigation pane (this is a known issue).

[image: Picture of two-column table format missing navigation pane]

If I make the right margin half the width of the page and reserve it for images that are attached to paragraphs with anchors, I can't get the text to reliably wrap or allow enough space to make room for the entire image in the margin, even using a text wrap break.

[image: Picture trying to get pictures in the margin to align with paragraphs]

The closest I've come to what I want (without tables) is by adding section breaks around each step, and making each section  two-column, but that's a hassle since it can't be automated with styles.

[Picture of section breaks around each step with two-columns inside each section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB7bO.png)

Has anyone found a satisfactory way to accomplish this in Microsoft Word 365?

Comment: Please post online an example page from your document. It will also help if you add a demo image that will show your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest a two-column table but you've already rejected that because the [heading does not show up in the navigation pane](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/headings-that-do-not-show-up-in-the-navigation/1d3bdc6d-218b-4b90-8e58-f1e0530f75bd). However, if that is your only objection...

### I suggest you still use a two column table and put a Table of Contents inside a frame or textbox on the left in your header.

This will give you the visual of the navigation.

If converted to pdf, the automatic hyperlinks in the TOC will work as will pdf hyperlinks.

### An alternative would be to place your illustrations inside frames.

Make the Frame formatting part of a style set to automatically follow your heading style. You can create frame formatting as a part of the modify style dialog.

Here is [my page on Textboxes and Frames](https://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#StartPage) in Microsoft Word.